# Laravel not publishing channels when called from api.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis, laravel-5.4

I am trying to implement a chat system with Laravel using Redis, Node, and socket.io. Anyways, when i try to publish the messages to Redis, i can do that using the web url, but when i call it from the API endpoints i have made in api.php, i get nothing. 
Here is how i am publishing the events to redis

```
public function index(){
        $data = [
            'event' => 'UserStuff',
            'data' => [
                'username'=>'Lord Haq'
            ]
        ];

        Redis::publish('test-channel-3', json_encode($data));
        return 'Hope this works!';
    }
```

This is the route in api.php

```
Route::get('redis', 'RedisController@index');
```

I have no idea what is going on. Or what other should i put here. Any help will be appreciated. Oh and i have `php artisan queue:listen` running in the background.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redis#pubsub

Comment: Yes, thank you for publishing a link to the docs. That did not occur to me to check the docs while i was looking at the docs, laracasts, and other sources on google after searching for hours. This definitely solves my problem.